# How to call in a method when you clicked a button

Tags: java, swing

Hi I am writing a little software. Here is how it works: You put in the textField any number and when you click the button it will showMessageDialog if it's a prime number or not.I have had my code down there but when I clicked the button nothing happens.I wonder what have I done wrong?I hope everyone can help me.Thank you

I have tried to change the code but it doesn't work

```
    JLabel lblPrimeNumberChecker = new JLabel("Prime number checker");
    lblPrimeNumberChecker.setBounds(160, 11, 117, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblPrimeNumberChecker);


    JButton btnReset = new JButton("Reset");
    btnReset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textNum.setText(null);

        }
    });
    btnReset.setBounds(271, 208, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnReset);

    textNum = new JTextField();
    textNum.setBounds(144, 42, 231, 20);
    contentPane.add(textNum);
    textNum.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Enter number");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(62, 45, 82, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    JButton btnCheck = new JButton("Check");
    btnCheck.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent checkPrime) {

        }
        private boolean checkPrime(int n) {
            int num=Integer.parseInt(textNum.getText());
             if(num<2) {
                 return false;
             }
             int h=(int)Math.sqrt(n);
             for(int i=2;i<=h;i++) {
                 if(n%i==0) {
                     return false;
                 }
             }
                    return true;     


        }
            void button_clicked() {
                int n=0;
                boolean isPrime=checkPrime(n);
                if(isPrime) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btnCheck, "Prime number", "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
                else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btnCheck, "Not prime number", "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            }


            });
    btnCheck.setBounds(62, 208, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnCheck);
```

I expect it will show you if it's a prime number or not when you have put in the textfield a number and clicked the button

Comment: You need to add an `ActionListener` to `btnCheck`, just as you did for `btnReset`. **Don't** add a `MouseListener` to `btnCheck`.

Answer (score 0):

All the calls to method `setBounds()`, in the code you posted, imply that you are using a GUI builder. Are you using an IDE? If so, which one? GUI builders can be useful for people who are proficient in writing *Swing* applications as they can save time, but I do not recommend them for learners. First learn to write *Swing* applications by writing all the code yourself. For example, it is hard to learn how to use layout managers when using a GUI builder. And layout managers, in my opinion, are a very important part of *Swing*.

I took the liberty of rewriting your app. The code is below. I suggest, assuming you haven't done so already, that you find a good resource that will help you learn how to write *Swing* applications. I recommend the online tutorial [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html). Even more I recommend the book [Core JFC (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013090581X) by Kim Topley. Yes it is quite old now, but nonetheless still very relevant.

Here is my code...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class PrimeNo implements Runnable {
    JFrame frame;
    JTextField textNum;

    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private boolean checkPrime(int n) {
        if (n < 2) {
            return false;
        }
        int h = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
        for (int i = 2; i <= h; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton btnReset = new JButton("Reset");
        btnReset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textNum.setText(null);
            }
        });
        buttonsPanel.add(btnReset);
        JButton btnCheck = new JButton("Check");
        btnCheck.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String str = textNum.getText();
                try {
                    int n = Integer.parseInt(str);
                    if (checkPrime(n)) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                                      "Prime number: " + str,
                                                      "Result",
                                                      JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                                      "Not prime number: " + str,
                                                      "Result",
                                                      JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException xNumFormat) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                                  "Not a number: " + str,
                                                  "Error",
                                                  JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });
        buttonsPanel.add(btnCheck);
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createInputPanel() {
        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Enter number");
        inputPanel.add(lblNewLabel);
        textNum = new JTextField(10);
        inputPanel.add(textNum);
        return inputPanel;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Prime Number Checker");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createInputPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrimeNo primeNo = new PrimeNo();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(primeNo);
    }
}
```